# Using Semicolons in Oracle SQL Statements

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

According to [an answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182534/how-long-does-it-take-to-become-reasonably-proficient-in-orcle-given-sql-server/183657#183657), semicolons are bad and should be avoided. I realized this firsthand after spending hours trying to figure out why my queries were running so terribly slow in SQL Developer. After removing the semicolon from the end of a complex query, it finished in a matter of seconds (compared to me just giving up on it after several minutes, which was the case before removing the semicolon). This behavior startled me, and a Google search didn't turn up much as to when and why I should or should not use semicolons in my SQL statements. Can anyone clear this up with a brief explanation?

Comment: btw you don't need semicolons in MSSQL server either

Comment: @HLGEM: but you should start using them in MSSQL as well: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not the semicolon.  Rerunning the same query meant that the rows were already cached, so you got them back much faster.

Comment: The semi-colon is a statement delimiter. In SQL*Plus if you did
update table_a set col_1=2;
/
The update statement would get automatically executed when the semi-colon was encountered. The slash would then run the current statement in the buffer (ie re-run the statement just executed);
Without the slash, and with SQL statements separated by blank lines, the statements would never be executed and simply discarded.  That would be very quick though :)
Different clients have different ways of executing statements.  SQL Developer's ctrl-return shouldn't care about a sem-colon on the end of an SQL

Answer (score 5):

I am coming from 5+ years of MS SQL Experience and 4+ years of Oracle Development. 
I know you will hate a lot of Oracle features, especially in SQL, ;) but take it easy. Oracle is a really powerful DBMS. Even though from lot of perspectives I prefer MSSQL over Oracle but that's a different topic.

As for your issue:

A semicolon is just a statement separator.

SQL developer is using Java and OCI so you might have different issues (I am just guessing something can be wrong).

If you feel something is not running right I advise you to get that query and run it in SQLPLUS instead of Visual Query Tools because it will give you the right feeling.

Good luck with Oracle development.

Visit [SQL*Plus FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a  book that will help tremendously
SQL in a Nutshell by Kevin and Daniel Kline

This has the syntax for both Oracle and SQl server so you can easily see how to convert things to Oracle syntax if you know how to write in t-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with Oracle as a developer from PowerBuilder, Java, .NET and TOAD for 10+ years this sounds strange.

I would suggest using explain plan to find what is happening and making sure the database is healthy, with proper statistics and indexes.

From earlier versions of Oracle I remember that using rule based optimization could lead to these kind of performance problems, but lately cost based optimization and statistics has made these kind of problems a thing of the past.